# Find any 1-1 function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking $f(n)=|n|$, but realized that would be a surjection. I'm not sure of how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Amy! What else have you tried? Could you expand on your problem? Are Z and N any set of numbers, or are integers and naturals? The more informatino the better help you'll get!

Comment: It's not the fact that this is a surjection is the problem, it's the fact that it's not injective.

Comment: @AngelusSilesius Hi, I apologize, N=natural numbers and Z=integers. I apologize.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You are right, simple concepts are slipping my mind. I do not know how to make this an injection though or anywhere close to it. Do you have any recommendations to try and help me solve this? (Not answers)

Comment: How about a map taking negative numbers to odd numbers and non-negative numbers to even numbers?

Comment: Great. Just for the future, there's special mathjax notation to write $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. Don't worry, there's no need to apologize!

Comment: From taking suggestions, would it work if I have f(n)=2n if n>0 and f(n)=|2n+1| for n<0?

Comment: What about $n=0$?

Comment: @AmyKulp I suggest trying the few smallest values to check yourself what the behavior is. This way, you can determine whether or not there are any cases where the same values occurs for $2$ different inputs, plus to ensure all natural numbers are in the set of results.

Comment: You could map 0 and the positive integers to the odd naturals; and the negatives to the evens.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I am actually not sure how to implement zero as my professor does not consider zero to be a natural number.

Comment: I was considering $0\in\mathbb Z$, $0\not\in\mathbb N$; the function you gave in a comment was the right idea, but you didn't define $f(0)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(n)=2(n+1)$ if $n\ge0$ and $-2n-1$ if $n<0$.

This maps {$0,1,2,...$} to {$2,4,6,...$} and {$-1,-2,-3,...$} to {$1, 3, 5, ...$};

i.e., {$..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...$} to {$1,2,3,4,5,6,...$}.

The inverse map is $f^{-1}(m)=\dfrac m 2 -1 $ if $m$ is even and $-\dfrac{m+1}2$ if $m$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x\,,x\gt0\\-2x+1\,,x\le0\end{cases}$

(As @J W Tanner commented.)

Answer (score 1):

Define $f$ as follows:

$$   
    f(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        2^n , & \text{when } n \ge 0 \\
        3^{|n|} , & \text{when } n \lt 0
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you one a closed formula for the function given by @Chris Custer, this works
$$f(x)=2|x|-\frac{x-\epsilon}{2|x-\epsilon|}+\frac{1}{2}$$
Here you can choose any $0<\epsilon<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:  let $f(n)=2^n $ if $n>0, 2^{-n}-1$ otherwise.